# HOC for JSX element - rendering jsx with wrapped element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to call a ReactJS HOC to wrap a tooltip around JSX.

The call should be able like this:

```js
withTooltip(JSX, "very nice")
```

Therefor I have created this function:

```js
import React from "react";
import MUITooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import useStyles from "./index.styles";

const withTooltip = (Component, text: string) => (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <MUITooltip className={classes.root} title={text}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </MUITooltip>
  );
};
export default withTooltip;
```

The call:

```js
import withTooltip from "commons/withTooltip/withTooltip";

  const dialogBtn =
    isOk &&
    withTooltip(
      <div className={classes.buttonWithLoader}>
        <OpenDialogButton
          variant={BaseButtonVariant.Icon}
          openDialogAttributes={areas.button.openDialogAttributes}
        />
      </div>,
      "Very nice",
    );
    
    
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {dialogBtn}
      </Fragment>
    );
```

It says:

**Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it**

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HOC accepts a `Component` argument while you are passing in JSX. Try wrapping the JSX with a function or pass in a component which renders the Button.

However, in your case, you probably want to have control over the toolTip text in your component. If this is the case, I would not use a HOC for this, but rather a wrapping Component.

```
function WithTooltip({ classes, text, children }) {
  return (
    <MUITooltip className={classes.root} title={text}>
      {children}
    </MUITooltip>
  );
}

export default WithTooltip;
```

```
const dialogBtn = isOk && (
  <WithTooltip text="Very nice">
    <div className={classes.buttonWithLoader}>
      <OpenDialogButton
        variant={BaseButtonVariant.Icon}
        openDialogAttributes={areas.button.openDialogAttributes}
      />
    </div>
  </WithTooltip>
);
```